# Check if $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_9 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Check if $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_9 \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a Homomorphism

I say, let $x,y \; \in \mathbb{Z}_9$.  $$\phi(x+y) = \phi(x+y)\pmod{2} = x +_2 y = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$$

However, this is wrong and I don't know why

Comment: I think you have messed up your TeX code. 

If what you mean is $\phi(x+y)=(x+y)\textrm{mod} 2 = x \textrm{mod} 2 + y \textrm{mod} 2 = \phi(x) +\phi(y)$, then I could help. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @DavidLawhorn I do not see what is wrong with it, but yes that is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi(4+5) = \phi(0) = 0$ But $\phi(4)+\phi(5)=1$

Answer (score 1):

[HINT:] If $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism and $x \in G$ has order $n$, then $\phi(x)$ has order dividing $n$. Thus, try to find an element of $Z_9$ whose order does not divide $\phi(x) \in Z_2$.